# win32 api reading file

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to read a file using WIN32 api but when I try to print one character it is completely gibberish
I tried to change the file encoding : unicode,ansi,utf-8 but the problem persist

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

TCHAR buff[512];
DWORD wr,pos;
DWORD bytesWritten;
DWORD len = (DWORD)strlen(buff);


 HANDLE f = CreateFile("test.txt",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

 if(f==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
    cout<"error";
 }



 ReadFile(f, buff ,len,&wr, NULL);

 cout<<buff[0];




 CloseHandle(f);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the output? Can you print it out?

Comment: Did you check the errorcode `ReadFile` returns? It fails because it cannot read from the file....

Comment: Also where is your <tchar.h> header?

Comment: it's printing ╪ but from the file that i read the first characther is l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the file for writing, then trying to read, is a main problem.

Also, the T stuff is ungood, but may not be doing you harm in this concrete example.

But get rid of that, and open the file for reading.

Simple bugs: the buffer length computation. You have an arbitrary string length. Obtain the buffer length with `std::end(buff) - std::begin(buff)`. Or a proper `sizeof` expression.

Also, reading into the buffer via API function does not make it zero-terminated. You need to retain the reported number of bytes read, and use that some way. E.g. to create a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

The `GENERIC_WRITE` mode opens the file without the ability to read it. If you want to read and write, change that to `GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`. If you only want to read, change to `GENERIC_READ`.

Also, the expression `strlen(buff)` will not give you the size of the buffer. Change to
`sizeof(buff) / sizeof(buff[0])`.